# How to FInd the sum of odd divisor of a number in Mathematica?

Tags: summation, number-theory

So I want to find the sum of odd divisors of a number raised to some power.
$i.e.$ I want to find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma'_{-2k-1}(n)$ where $\sigma'_{-2k-1}(n) = \sum_{d|n, \text{d odd}} d^{-2k-1}$.

How should I go with this? Using `DivisorSigma[k,n]` just sums up over all the divisors.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you remove all powers of 2from your number and sum the full set of divisors?

Comment: For the infinite sum, since $1$ is an odd divisor of all $n$ and $1^{-2k-1}=1$, the sum diverges, no?

Comment: You could just brute force it. Find the divisors, filter out the odds, raise them to the -(2*k+1)th and total: `Total[Select[Divisors[n],OddQ]^(-2*k-1)]` Probably something more clever out there.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, you are right. There is some exponential terms as well with very high negative powers which I have not written here. I am mainly interested to know how can I write code for this sum in mathematica.

Comment: `DivisorSigmaPrime[r_, n_Integer] := DivisorSigma[r, NestWhile[#/2 &, n, EvenQ]]` will get you $\sigma_r(n)$. Then `Sum[]` can be used for the summation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks a lot! Well, I have to think about it, as I'm not familiar with Nest in Mathematica, but this works for now :)

Comment: You're welcome. I meant $\sigma_r'(n)$ instead of $\sigma_r(n)$ in the previous comment, but maybe that's obvious. I should point out that my code is basically what @Daniel recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could find the sum of odd divisors of a number raised to some power in the following way:

```
DivisorSum[n, #^(-2k-1) &, OddQ]
```

You can then use Sum[ ] for summation.

Comment: `DivisorSum[]` is indeed the appropriate tool to use here.

Answer (score 5):

To incorporate comments, for the sake of completeness:
Of the three current suggestions in the comments and answer, Daniel Lichtblau's is fastest:

```
DivisorSigmaPrime // ClearAll;
DivisorSigmaPrime[r_, n_Integer] := 
  DivisorSigma[r, NestWhile[#/2 &, n, EvenQ]];
```

It's literally a divide-and-conquer approach, as dividing out twos removes the even divisors.

```
k = 2;
Table[Total[Select[Divisors[n], OddQ]^(-2*k - 1)], {n, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[DivisorSum[n, #^(-2 k - 1) &, OddQ], {n, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Table[DivisorSigmaPrime[-2 k - 1, n], {n, 10000}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Clear[n, k];
(*
  {0.253292, Null}  -- @Lusine
  {0.172394, Null}  -- @N.J.Evans
  {0.108652, Null}  -- @Daniel
*)
```

The differences are greater the more factors there are.

```
(* no even divisors *)
SeedRandom[0];
k = 2;
n = 2^0 Apply[Times]@Prime[RandomInteger[{10, 1000}, 10]];
DivisorSum[n, #^(-2 k - 1) &, OddQ] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
Total[Select[Divisors[n], OddQ]^(-2*k - 1)] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
DivisorSigmaPrime[-2 k - 1, n] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
Clear[n, k];
(*
  {0.00940233,   1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @Lusine
  {0.00823647,   1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @N.J.Evans
  {0.0000936843, 1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @Daniel
*)

(* many even divisors *)
SeedRandom[0];
k = 2;
n = 2^20 Apply[Times]@Prime[RandomInteger[{10, 1000}, 10]];
DivisorSum[n, #^(-2 k - 1) &, OddQ] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
Total[Select[Divisors[n], OddQ]^(-2*k - 1)] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
DivisorSigmaPrime[-2 k - 1, n] - 1 // RepeatedTiming // N[#, 20] &
Clear[n, k];
(*
  {0.0259015,   1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @Lusine
  {0.023558,    1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @N.J.Evans
  {0.000116666, 1.4631160740223029704*10^-13}  -- @Daniel
*)
```

I didn't find much variation in relative timings if `k` is changed. (Large `n` and `k` leads to lots of bigInt calculations, and all three methods slow down.)